# Read And Normalize an Agilent Dataset in MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab

I have an Agilent dataset. When I use R for reading it, I create a file which is called target file, which is a txt file containing all the sample txt. How can we read all the sample in MATLAB as R?

the code in matlab is :

```
AGFEData = agferead(File) 
%//example:
agfeStruct = agferead('fe_sample.txt')
```

We use quantile normalization in R. And how we normalize it in MATLAB,  the normalization code in MATLAB for a micro array is `XNorm = manorm(X)`.